# Flutter java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, flutter, androidx, flutter-plugin, appcompatactivity

I am writing a flutter plugin which will start an Activity from the plugin and this Activity has to be AppCompactActivity

I have this dependency in both the app and the plugin dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

but I am getting this error once startActivity called and the app crashes

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.util.GeneratedPluginRegister.registerGeneratedPlugins(GeneratedPluginRegister.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.configureFlutterEngine(FlutterActivity.java:928)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:180)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity;
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory;
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Pt2eWtOSiNwV3ewUp8Bkfw==/Pa4pjhLz_vC1nMrdJxNEEg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Pt2eWtOSiNwV3ewUp8Bkfw==/Pa4pjhLz_vC1nMrdJxNEEg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~Pt2eWtOSiNwV3ewUp8Bkfw==/Pa4pjhLz_vC1nMrdJxNEEg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1212):    ... 21 more
I/Process ( 1212): Sending signal. PID: 1212 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Why does it have to be an AppCompatActivity? You can extend FlutterActivity and that's mostly enough for anything

Comment: getting this error  Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#( 6392): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?